# Are URI's with a double hash (##) invalid?

Tags: ruby, uri, fragment-identifier

I have URI that contains `##` (e.g. `http://foo.com/bar##baz`) . Ruby's `URI.parse` function throws an error when I try to parse it.

Are double hash marks forbidden in URIs? Or is the Ruby Parser too strict?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple fragment identifiers correct in URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714268/multiple-fragment-identifiers-correct-in-url)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Fragment Identifiers](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) may not contain a hash sign. The parser is correct.

The syntax for a fragment identifier is defined as follows:

```
fragment = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
```

[`pchar` is defined as](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3):

```
pchar = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

[`unreserved`](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3), [`pct-encoded`](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) and [`sub-delims`](http://Tools.IETF.Org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) are defined as:

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG

sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Answer (score 3):

They are invalid. A `#` indicates that the remainder is a *fragment*, and a *fragment* may not have a `#` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Addressable allows it:

```
require 'addressable/uri'
Addressable::URI.parse('http://foo.com/bar##baz').fragment
#=> "#baz"
```

Addressable is supposed to conform more closely to the rfc's, but wko knows. I would say it's subject to interpretation.