# Multiple parameters in URL fragment

Tags: html, url, uri, url-parameters, fragment-identifier

Is there a standard format that allows for multiple parameters to be specified in the URI fragment? (the part after the hash `#`, **not** the query string.)

The most related information would be this question: [Multiple fragment identifiers correct in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714268/multiple-fragment-identifiers-correct-in-url). The allowed characters for fragments can be found in that question as well.

Would it be acceptable to use, for instance, a semicolon to delimit multiple parameters like this:

```html
http://example.net/page.html?q=1#param1=foo;param2=bar
```

Are there any unintentional behaviours that I should be aware of with this method? What if there is no such ID in the document with the value `param1`?

For the purposes of this question, only URIs of HTML resources are considered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Examples

So the de-facto standard format for multiple parameters should be `#param1=value1&param2=value2`
You can see this way is used by [Media Fragments URI 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) and by PDF documents. There seems to be no standard for HTML resources though as you can parse the fragment in JavaScript in any way you like. But I'd use the same format as it looks more natural being similar to the query string format. If the browser cannot find any element with id/name equal to your hash fragment, it will navigate to the beginning of the document by default.

Also browsers will consider the complete hash fragment as a possible id/name. So they will look for id/name equal to `param1=value1&param2=value2` but not just `param1`.

Comment: Besides if you're interested in making your AJAX application crawlable by search engines, here is a guide from Google about using hash fragment #!
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?csw=1

Comment: Thanks. Now that's deprecated https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html