# Handle anchors link (fragments) in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, internet-explorer-9

I'm using **Backbone.js** but as **IE9** doesn't support the **pushState API**, the URL is converted from `/page` to `/#page`.

The challenge is that I need to take care about `<a href="#section">Go to section</a>` fragments, but once clicked, the fragment part `#section` will be removed from URL (not added) and I need it for sharing.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"the last part will be removed"_?

Comment: Also, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited my detailed question, please check

Comment: You mean that the url is `#section` instead of `/#page#section` ?

Comment: it should be someting like `/#page#section` but it is only `/#page`

Comment: That's not how fragment works...

Comment: @EmileBergeron what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you need `#page#section` just use

```
<a href="#page/section">Go to section</a>
```

Anchor links are completely replaced on click.

From [Multiple fragment identifiers correct in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715958/1218980)

> From the specification point of view, a
> [fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) can contain
> the following characters (I’ve already expanded the productions):
>
> ```
> fragment    = *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG  "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / > ";" / "=" / ":" / "@" / "/" / "?" )
> ```
>
> So, no, the fragment must not contain a plain `#`; it must be encoded
> with `%23`.

This means that `#page#section` is not a valid fragment.

---

If after each click, the URL is back to `#page`, it's probably because you are replacing the fragment manually somewhere, like

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#page');
```

---

If you can't modify the HTML, you could make a new route:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'page': 'pageRoute',
        'section': 'sectionRoute'
    },

    pageRoute: function() {

    },
    sectionRoute: function() {

    }
});
```

Comment: @BarbuBarbu I updated the answer the best I could with the provided details, but you should really clarify your question further.